# PowerPoint: Is there a way to use PowerPoint as a 'CMS'? i.e. I create a template with assets & folder., and my client can replace the assets

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, template-design, template, content

I am using PowerPoint to design a series of templates for my client. (Yes, I know PPT is not the most ideal solution, but that was the decision)

This will be used to display some text & image content, along with ppt animations & slide transitions. This powerpoint slide will be beamed up to a large LED display and essentially function as a 'looping video wall'. Kind of like the video walls in Apple Stores.

The reason for having it in powerpoint is so that the client can easily edit the images & text on their own, which they intend to do periodically.

**My Question:**

I was wondering if there is some function in PowerPoint that allows it to act as a 'CMS' of sorts - asset browser, text editor etc. so that my client can easily replace the images, without manually right-clicking to 'Replace Image' on each individual image.

**Is there some way to link a powerpoint file to a folder /img with a bunch of images,** a clear naming structure (img001.jpg, img002.jpg ...) and then the client can simply replace the image & text there, rather than fiddle around manually in powerpoint?

Comment: No that's not possible. Or at leat not without plugin. With LiveWeb plugin some coding and a ftp program it may be possible to get something similar to what you want, but won't be easier to edit than the normal way.

Comment: I don't know how practical this will be, but you can link OLE objects from Microsoft Office applications, which act as external linked files.  The limitation is that the imported content has to be from an application that supports OLE objects - so, essentially an object from another MS Office product. [see more info here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-content-from-other-applications-into-powerpoint-8165a079-e639-4278-81be-8b3ee94f81fb)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a VBA script to update (import) the numerous images into the .ppt?  There are plenty of examples to Google.

If you have a slide, who's image file you update often, automate the process using a VBA procedure (macro), as follows:

- In PowerPoint, launch the Visual Basic Editor by pressing
  [Alt]+[F11]. Choose Module from the Insert menu. Enter the following
  subprocedure:

  Sub InsertLogo()
  'Insert TR logo
  ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
  FileName:="C:\Active\TR\September2009Blog\TR.jpg", _
  LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
  SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=60, Top:=35, _
  Width:=98, Height:=48).Select
  End Sub

Reference: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-vba-to-insert-a-picture-file-onto-a-powerpoint-slide/

In all Likeliness, it sounds like the end user would be better off with a dedicated signage software, that can retrieve images, format them and load them for display.   Raspberry Pi is a good platform